# Хостинг API на Python с БД на PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, api, hosting

У меня есть API, который при запуске создает базу данных со всеми таблицами и связями, CRUD функции осуществляются самой апишкой посредством енд-пойнт запросам. Локально на пк все работает, но тут возникла цель переноса апишки на хостинг, чтобы любой пользователь, скачавший и установивший приложение на андроид, смог взаимодействовать с программой исключительно через интернет. В докере не силен, да и в пуше на хостинг вообще, возник такой вопрос: как это осуществить? Чтобы моя апишка была удаленная + работала корректно с БД (т.е. при прогоне создалась бы бдшка и существовала в каком-то пространстве, функционируя корректно с запросами от апи). Прочекал бесплатные хостинги, но нашел только сервис Back4App, но все равно в нем не уверен. Знатоки, есть тут кто?

Пробовал с самого начала запихнуть апи в контейнер, но имэдж с апи стопается..

Answer (score 0):

Заведите проект на github, залейте туда свой код, дальше получите доступ к серверу ( обычно это ip, пароль и username), дальше через ssh

```
ssh username@ip
*вводите пароль*
git clone (ссылка на репозиторий github)
*запускаете приложение*
```

после этого можно будет кидать запросы на сервер вида *ip сервера*/get_users и тп

p.s. для того, чтобы после выхода с сервера приложение продолжило работать, можно воспользоваться docker-ом, но я бы посоветовал начать с [tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki) - это проще и быстрее